# Maven dependencies conflicts after selenium upgrade

Tags: java, selenium, maven

Recently I had to upgrade selenium version form 3.6.x to 4.0.0. After that I started have a problem when I use some of the features in my project. Basicly the NoClassDefFoundError is thrown when I am trying to use class that is using PageFactory:

```
ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/internal/WrapsElement

at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultFieldDecorator.proxyForLocator(DefaultFieldDecorator.java:101)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultFieldDecorator.decorate(DefaultFieldDecorator.java:62)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.proxyFields(PageFactory.java:113)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:105)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:92)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:79)
```

I checked and after upgrading to Selenium 4.0.0 the WrapsElement interface is no longer in a org/openqa/selenium/internal/ package but instead it is now in org/openqa/selenium/.
My question is how I can fix it - how I can force Maven to resolve these dependency to use WrapsElement in a correct location?

```
package org.openqa.selenium;
@FunctionalInterface
public interface WrapsElement {
  WebElement getWrappedElement();
}
```

Comment: You can't force maven to change the of such thing because the maintainers of Selenium have decided to make (breaking) changes which is expectable during a major version upgrade... simple solution is: You have to fix your code... Also this kind of changes is documented (https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2021/announcing-selenium-4/) also there have been a lot of release in between 3.6.X and now.. which means you have never upgrade to for example 3.7...and so and there have been deprecation warning (if you have upgraded) in your build which could alerted you to migrate the code over the time...

Comment: BTW: 4.0.0 is not the most recent version ... https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api also check https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases

Comment: Thanks. Yes I know that in meantime there have been many other releases and 4.0.0 is not the latest one. I just joined the team working on it and for me it is legacy like.               Anyway I just wander how can I fix the code if WrapsElement interface is invoked somwhere by library class. So basicly I have no access to the source of the selenium classes. Likely I have to dig in project's code to find out how this interface is invoked? But even if I will find it out still have no idea hot could i fix the way the WrapsElement is invoke by the selenium class - DefaultFieldDecorator ?

Comment: First if you use it as a dependency the code can be downloaded automatically via your IDE (during investigation of the your code)... has to be configured in your IDE... What will that help if you try to find why selenium is doing such things? you have to fix your code... that's it...migrate to newer version... Thats a technical deps which has piled over the times...